# Different size collectionviewcells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

http://postimg.org/image/6bws3catp/

As you can see on the image I need something that gives me the possibility of resizing a cell depending on the length of the text that contains.

I' ve been trying to do that with a UICollectionview but the cells have always the same size and if I try to alterate the size playing with the frame.size and location parameters the scroll gets crazy.

Maybe the UICollectionView isn't the best choice...

Thank you very much

EDIT:

Because of your answers my cells are able to change dynamically their size but the margins aren't behaving as I expected.

The margins of the cells depends always on the biggest cell of the same row

http://postimg.org/image/3scthf9rv/

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
return 6;
}
```

I have implement this to set my margin value between cells in 6 points, but maybe this only works when you have one cell in each row in a vertical collection view..

Thank you again for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can check out https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout . Looks
   like something you can use for this...
2. you can override the following method and return a CGSize object that specifies the size you want to use for each cell. Using this method, you can actually have each cell be a different size:

   ```
   - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   ```

Example:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}
```

Your view controller needs to be a delegate of UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in order for this method to be called. So don't forget to add that delegate declaration to your view controller's .h file, such as:

```
@interface MyViewController () <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you help me with the new margin problem ?

Comment: @AndoniMuruamendiaraz what is your problem?

Comment: I have edited the question to explain it better, or it is better to create a new question? Sorry I am new over here :)

Comment: @AndoniMuruamendiaraz ok i'm giving you a sample code link for that: https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout

Comment: Finally I have done it with you your first recommendation (RFQuiltLayout). Thank you very much!! You are a lifesafer!!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have enough reputation to do it.

Comment: @AndoniMuruamendiaraz ok no prob

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView` is the correct choice. You just need to customise the flow layout attributes.

Read [Customizing the Flow Layout Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html)

Specifically you would need to implement Collection View Delegate method:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  // In this method you can calculate the size of the string for each cell
  UIFont *font = // font to create the text for each cell
  NSString *string = // text string for each cell
  CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont];
  return size;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!Your help has been very useful. Could you help me with the margin stuff?